# Controls Disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a wpf project on a windows embedded standard sp3 operating system and I noticed that occasionally controls disappear or parts of it go missing.  This can only be reproduced when using the xp embedded machine so it may have something to do with the drivers or operating system.  I thought it might have been related to using the aero theme, but the issue still persists even though it was completely removed.  In the screenshot below there should be two buttons under the "24" button but they disappeared for some reason.  You can see part of the control being partially rendered.  I have also seen text boxes cut in half and progress bars not being rendered properly. Has anyone seen this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using snoop to get an idea if the element is rendered by obscured or simply not rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this happened because I was using the Blur effect on the styling of each of the buttons which the hardware could not handle properly.

Answer (score 2):

Standard bat-signal sign of violating threading requirements.  Don't mess with controls in a worker thread.

Comment: Does that include changing collections bound to a control using a background worker?  What would be an alternative?

Comment: Absolutely.  Especially nasty because that doesn't raise an InvalidOperationException like you'd normally get when you try to update a control directly.  One of the many ways that binding sux.  The solution is to only collect the data in the worker.  `List<Mumble>`, whatever fits.  The binding has to happen on the UI thread, in the RunWorkerCompleted event for example.

Comment: Why does this not happen in any other computer I use? I have changed it so any object that is bound to the xaml goes through the gui thread and the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Hmm, count yourself very lucky to *have* a machine where this goes wrong.  It is *much* worse when it goes bad on your customer's machine but not yours.  Which is the more typical outcome.

Comment: So my issue has nothing to do with threading requirements since all interaction with the controls through binding is now forced on the GUI thread.

Comment: Well, of course it does.  Didn't binding on the UI thread instead of the worker solve your problem?

Comment: No.  Turns out using the Blur Effect on 30 controls was too much for the computer to handle.  Once I removed that effect the issue disappeared.

Comment: Hmya, altering thread timing also changes the odds for threading races causing problems.  Just like running it on another machine does.  Now you'll need to find another machine that exhibits problems.  Your customer might have one.